# Can I ignore aspect of a method while mocking it using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, aspects

I have a class with a few methods advised through an input validation aspect (validates whether all input parameters are not-null/non-empty strings).

I am facing an issue while writing test case for them and want to verify if this is indeed a bad design issue.

Here's a very simplified version of my class:

```
public class A {

public String one(String word) {
// Some actions
String val = two(word2);
// Some more actions
}

protected String two(String word) {
// Some actions
}

}
```

Now while writing test cases for `one()` I use Mockito and want to mock calls to `two()`. So I use:

```
@Spy
A a;

@Test
void test() {
doReturn("Bye").when(A).two(Mockito.anyString());

a.one("hello");
// Some validations
}
```

This test fails as the:  `doReturn()` line fails with input being empty for `two()`.

Should I not mock `two()` or can I make this work somehow?

**Edit**: 
Adding a more specific example related to the two methods being present in two different classes as requested:

Create a page through a WebService. This builds a putRequest, executes it and returns a response.

```
public class AUtility implements BaseUtility {
    public Response create(Params params) {

        try {
            PutMethod putRequest = buildPUTRequest(params.getAttr1(), params.getAttr2());
            return Utils.buildResponse(client.executeMethod(putRequest),
                                                     params.getAttr3(),
                                                     params.getAttr4());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AppException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The put request marshals the data into a file to write it through the HttpClient

```
private PutMethod buildPUTRequest(final String url, final Object obj) throws IOException, JAXBException {

    // Create a temp file to store the stream
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(APPLICATION_LABEL, XML_LABEL);
    decoder.marshal(obj, tempFile);

    // Build the put method

    return putMethod;
}
```

XMLMarshaller

```
public interface XMLDecoder implement Decoder {

    public void marshal(Object obj, File tempFile) throws IOException, JAXBException {
    // Perform marshalling operations 
    }
}
```

The test fails on line2 with the inputs being null.

```
@Test
public void createPageParamsHttpException() throws HttpException, IOException, JAXBException {
    expectedException.expect(AppException.class);
    doNothing().when(decoder).marshal(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(File.class));
    doThrow(HttpException.class).when(client).executeMethod(Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class));

    Params params = new Params(new Application(), 
                           APPLICATION_URL_LABEL, 
                                 SITE_NAME_LABEL,
                         URL_WITHOUT_HTTP_N_HTML);

    utility.createPage(params);
}
```

Any idea how should I proceed for the same?

Comment: One more thing that I can do is:
Instead of Mockito.anyString() for the doReturn()... pass the actual value as in: 
doReturn("Bye").when(A).two(word2);

However, this just feels worse than simply not mocking two().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You don't want to do this.

You are inherently changing the behavior of the class. If you change what `two()` does, how do you know that `one()` will do what it's supposed to do in production?

If you truly want to do this, you should extract the behavior of `two()` into another top level class, and then inject the dependency into `A`. Then you can mock this dependency and you don't have to worry about going to the trouble of creating a partial mock for `A`.

In a similar vein, if you must keep `two` in the same class (because it's behavior is part of the same responsibility that is assigned to `A` - see the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - why is it `public`?

---

The reason you are having trouble is because you are violating the SRP, see my note above. You said this:

> This builds a putRequest, executes it and returns a response.

You should not be trying to test the behavior of all three of those things at the same time. Ultimately, this method does not really do anything. The `buildPUTRequest` method does, and shouldn't be in a class called `AUtility`, it should be in a class `RequestFactory`. Then, you would want to test the `Utils.buildResponse` method, except that shouldn't be in a class called `Utils`, it should be in a class called `Responder` or something... and this method ABSOLUTELY should not be `static`.

Work on naming your classes better things, and if you can't come up with a good name, that means the class probably does too much and should be refactored. And a method that wraps the work in two other methods doesn't need to be unit tested. Integration tested, perhaps, but that's another story.

Comment: well, the intention is to effectively do a black-box test of the one() and mock all of it's dependencies where two() has it's own set of tests.

However, I am too thinking of going ahead with moving two() to another class.

As for the last question: corrected the code sample. two() is protected. Does this change something?

Comment: Read this: [Why shouldn't I test private methods?](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-shouldnt-i-test-private)

Comment: thanks for the article. A quick read this makes this seem like a case of design smell and I should either 1. test two() using one() or 2. if two() handles entirely different responsibility, move it another class.

But if I do go ahead with 2, the above question remains same.
As soon as I mock the now external dependency, the aspect would fail the test-case.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I can't answer that question without knowing more about the behavior of `one`

Comment: Added a more specific example.

Comment: @Mohitk I replied to you. Also I recommend reading [Clean Code](http://amzn.com/0132350882)

Comment: Thanks.
I went ahead by changing a few things in the test to remove the need for the actual question.